# getJSON with [ ] doesn't work

Tags: json, api, get, getjson

I'm not very experienced in this stuff, but I simply call an API wich returns me this

```
[
   {
      "beatmapset_id":"18860",
      "beatmap_id":"66609",
      "approved":"2",
      "approved_date":"2010-08-15 10:04:19",
      "last_update":"2010-08-15 10:00:44",
      "total_length":"468",
      "hit_length":"447",
      "version":"Legend",
      "artist":"DragonForce",
      "title":"Revolution Deathsquad",
      "creator":"Lesjuh",
      "bpm":"250",
      "source":"",
      "difficultyrating":"3.95095",
      "mode":"0"
   }
]
```

my html :

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

$.getJSON('whatever.html', function(fbResults) {

document.write(fbResults.beatmapset_id);

     });

});
```

Now the problem is, it doesn't work this way, but it works if I remove the "[" and "]" from the JSON code.

Well, I can't just tell the guy who made this API to remove those, what could I do?

Edit: There is another problem now.
https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=5051a27169de8f360636fb0c3a108e8a3dab24b2&b&b=66609
if I take this as the link, it doesn't work.
I tried it with callback but this doens't work either.
https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=5051a27169de8f360636fb0c3a108e8a3dab24b2&b&b=66609?callback=?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets means that this is an array containing one item.

To get the first (and only) item in this array, simply append [0] to it.

In your example:

```
document.write(fbResults[0].beatmapset_id);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but something still doesn't work.
https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=5051a27169de8f360636fb0c3a108e8a3dab24b2&b&b=66609
When I am using this as link, it doesn't work, but when I copy what is inside this and put it into an html, it works. That's awkward.

Comment: @user356608 - This is because of your source. It needs to provide the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" to be accessible via jquery's `getJSON` method. That's a different problem to your original question.

Comment: Oh, okey. Does this basically mean I will not be able to work with their API until they change it?

Comment: @user356608 - There might be a workaround, I don't know of one though.

Answer (score 0):

Try `fbResults[0].beatmapset_id`

EDIT: See Andrew Shepherd's answer for more explanation :P

Comment: I'm sorry, but something still doesn't work. https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=5051a27169de8f360636fb0c3a108e8a3dab24b2&b&b=66609
 When I am using this as link, it doesn't work, but when I copy what is inside this and put it into an html, it works. That's awkward.